# Mqtt message delivery when user will come online

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, mqtt, message-queue, publish-subscribe, mosquitto

**Is it possible to use mqtt+mosquitto (or any broker like rabbitmq, redis) for the purpose of push notification instead of FCM ?**

Let's assume we are using mqtt+mosquitto.

I am explaining my needed scenario:

An user **A** is sending a message to user **B** but the user **B** is now offline. Whenever user **B** will come online he should be notified about his pending message.

**How to implement this scenario with broker**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MQTT has a concept of "persistent sessions". There's a flag called "clean session" that the client sends to the broker in the connect packet when first connecting. By setting this flag to false, the client is asking the broker to "remember me".

Then if the client disconnects or loses it's connection, the broker will hold messages for the client until the next time it reconnects, and send them to the client in the order received.

In MQTT, each client is required to have a unique "ClientID". This is how the broker recognizes the client when it reconnects. The client uses subscriptions to tell the broker what messages that it wants the first time it connects, and then after that the broker remembers the list of subscriptions for that client and all the messages that match those subscriptions.

So, for your scenario, Client **B** would need to connect once with a persistent session, and then *after* that, the broker will hold messages for it whenever it disconnects.

Comment: You will also need to subscribe to the relevant topics at QOS 1 or 2 as QOS 0 messages are not queued even with a persistent session by default.